# Rewrite Drupal files directory to sub folder

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am 'merging' two Drupal sites into one multisite installation. But one of the sites has the files saved at `<drupal root>/files` while the other one saves them at `<drupal root>/files/site-2` (which actually is a symlink to `<drupal root>/sites/site-2/files`). Now I'm looking for a way to 'merge' them without loosing the url structure of my site-1, i.e. I want

`http://site-1.com/files` to display `http://site-1/files/site-1`
and keep `http://site-2.com/files/site-2` as it was.

I imagine that this can be done through a simple .htaccess mod_rewrite operation, but I don't know much about that. I was trying

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site-1.com  
RewriteRule ^/files(.*)?$ /files/site-1$1 [NC]
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Background question: Are the files handled through Drupal's files table, or uploaded independently?

Comment: They're handled through Drupal's files table. Most of them are imagefields, some are Audio module's audio files. Additionally, there are some manually uploaded files.

Comment: It could also be an option not to use symlinks at all and do all the rewrite stuff through mod_rewrite. But I am lacking skills to accomplish that..

Comment: Hm, nobody? Actually I think the question might be even easier and not necessarily Drupal related: What would the rewrite have to look like if I wanted users to "see" the URL `http://site-1.com/files` but serve them the files in `http://site-1.com/sites/site-1.com/files`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic: The server configuration wasn't correct so that the directives didn't work. Grrr. My solution is now like I said in my first 'answer': Change the paths to use the sub directory and then redirect old files to that folder:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site-1.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/site-1/.*$ 
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ /files/site-1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I think internal Drupal paths don't work with rewrites (for example imagecache). That's why I chose this option.

fyi: The replace stuff I used to change the paths in the database is this (in phpmyadmin):

```
UPDATE files SET filepath = REPLACE(filepath,'files/','files/site-1/'); 
UPDATE node_revisions SET body = REPLACE(body,'src="/files/','src="/files/site-1/'); 
UPDATE node_revisions SET teaser = REPLACE(teaser,'src="/files/','src="/files/site-1/'); 
UPDATE boxes SET body = REPLACE(body,'src="/files/','src="/files/site-1/');
```